# How to list empty count in query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

On the sheet "Telefon" I calculate values to generate invoices from.

To have an overview of the calculated values, there are querys in E6, H6 and K6. Unfortunately, I can't manage to count the blank values so that the values are displayed in the correct row.

[image]

[image]

i.e. the values in H7:J7 should be in H14:J14

This is the query I use in H6:

```
=QUERY(Archiv!A1:AA,"
select count(R), sum(U)
where N contains 'person2' and W contains '"&$C2&"'
group by V
limit 12
label count(R) 'Tage', sum(U) 'Anzahl'
",1)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in **Cell_H6**:*

```js
=map(B7:B18,lambda(Σ,hstack(
countifs(Archiv!R:R,"<>",Archiv!V:V,Σ,Archiv!N:N,"Person2",index(year(Archiv!W:W)),C2),
sumifs(Archiv!U:U,Archiv!V:V,Σ,Archiv!N:N,"Person2",index(year(Archiv!W:W)),C2))))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is getting very close to what I want, but unfortunately the annual filter (C2) is not taken into account.

Comment: Add the extra condition check `Archiv!W:W,C2` to both the **countifs** and **sumifs**

Comment: I added the extra condition but now there are no values at all.

Comment: =map(B7:B18,
lambda(Σ,hstack(countifs(Archiv!R:R,"<>",Archiv!V:V,Σ,Archiv!N:N,"Person2",Archiv!W:W,C2),
sumifs(Archiv!U:U,Archiv!V:V,Σ,Archiv!N:N,"Person2",Archiv!W:W,C2))))

Comment: Share a test sheet for further troubleshooting OR wait for others to pitch in with alternate solutions

Comment: oh sorry, shoud be accessible now

Comment: Almost, it shows everything correct for 2023 but not for 2024

Comment: that's because you have your **month-dates** in `B7:B18` for Dec-22 to Nov 23; why would it reflect 2024 data just by changing it in C2 drop-down?! you have to make some sort of setup to change the month-dates as well when you select the appropriate year

Comment: Got it! I have made a query to the "Dropdowns" sheet to get the right mounts/years. Thank you very much, works perfect!